# Unable to get user input in PL in sqldeveloper

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedures

I'm trying to get user input in SQLDeveloper in a procedure. But however , I'm getting some error like "missing defines". Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE
a NUMBER(5);    
BEGIN
a := :a;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('We took the number as ' || a);
END;
```

The error looks like this.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
a NUMBER(5);    
BEGIN
a := :a;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('We took the number as ' || a);
END;
Error report -
Missing defines
We took the number as 15
```

Although I'm getting the correct answer at bottom, still why this errors?

Comment: I am not facing any error in sqldeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the below statement:

```
  DECLARE
    a NUMBER(5):=15;    
    BEGIN
    a := a;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('We took the number as ' || a);
    END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want user input.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get user input in PLSQL Block, we use &, &givenumber will get the user input at run  time.

```
DECLARE
a NUMBER(5);    
BEGIN
a := &givenumber;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('We took the number as ' || a);
END;
```